# To know if a quadrilateral intersects another one

Tags: intersection, quadrilaterals

I'm looking for an algorithm that allows me to know if a quadrilateral intersects another one. I'm not interested in the intersection itself, I just want to know if it exists.

I have found solutions like the one proposed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141798/two-quadrilaterals-intersection-area-special-case

But my problem is simpler than the person who wrote this post so there may be a simpler solution too.

Comment: Typically, you show what you've tried, and what you're stuck on. Please see the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for more guidance.

Comment: I think you just need to check if at least one vertex of the second quadrilateral is inside the first one, if this is the case, then there is an intersection.  If none of the vertices satisfy this then you check if at least one vertex of the first quadrilateral is inside the second quadrilateral, if so, then there is an intersections. If none of the vertices satisfy this, then no intersection happens.

Comment: David Culbreth : Thank you for your answer! Precisely for the moment I haven't tried anything because I haven't found a satisfactory way to do it.  That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Nerdrigo : What you propose is not correct, many counter-examples exist